# Joomla Error Message File Directory

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I was trying to learn how to create a joomla template. I successfully override some modules and components on my template however I can't override the error message especially on form validation.

I would like to know where the files are located and is it possible to override? My purpose is to add some bootsrap classes and add more tags on it.

Comment: What the error messages and after what deals? You can search templates at /templates/(name_of_template)

Comment: I just want to replace the css class of the error message the problem is that I don't know where to look for the php file

Answer (score 1):

The actual generated system message is in /layouts/joomla/system/message.php

```html
<div id="system-message-container">
  <?php if (is_array($msgList) && !empty($msgList)) : ?>
  <div id="system-message">
    <?php foreach ($msgList as $type => $msgs) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $type; ?>">
      <?php // This requires JS so we should add it trough JS. Progressive enhancement and stuff. ?>
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>

      <?php if (!empty($msgs)) : ?>
      <h4 class="alert-heading">
        <?php echo JText::_($type); ?>
      </h4>
      <div>
        <?php foreach ($msgs as $msg) : ?>
        <div class="alert-message">
          <?php echo $msg; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I check the code and I have found another mystery. Where do the massages come from $msgList = $displayData['msgList']. How do this generated?

Comment: Try /libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/message.php

Answer (score 0):

You can fix template CSS at `/template/(your_template)/css/template.css`
Or you can make new CSS with `/template/(your_template)/css/my.css`
and include it in the `/template/(your_template)/index.php`:

```
$doc->addStyleSheetVersion($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/my.css');
```

If you need to temporary override CSS class from your CSS you can use " !important" about the overrided attribe in the CSS file.